# Is H a subgroup of R$^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

H = {a + b$\sqrt{3} \in R^*$|a, b $\in Q$}. Is H a subgroup of $R^*$?
1 $\notin$ H so H should not be a subgroup, but the answer is given that it is a subgroup.

Comment: Well, if you take $a=1$ and $b=0$ you have $1 \in H$.

Comment: Why isn't $1 + 0 \cdot \sqrt 3$ an element of $H$?

Comment: Of course you must exclude the one element where $a=b=0$.

Comment: The a=b=0 case is not in $R^*$ thus not in $H$ by the definition the question gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H is a subgroup of $R^*$.

- $1 = 1 + 0\cdot \sqrt{3} \in H$
- If $ x = a_x + b_x \sqrt{3} \in H$ and $ y = a_y + b_y \sqrt{3}\in H $ then 
  $xy = a_xa_y + 3b_xb_y + (a_xb_y + b_x a_y)\sqrt{3} \in H$
- Associativity is inheritted from the group structure of $R^*$

What remains is to show that if $x = a + b \sqrt{3} \in H$ then $x^{-1} \in H$. But
unless $a^2 - 3b^2 = 0$,

$$
x^{-1} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{3}}{a^2 - 3b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2 - 3b^2} -\frac{b}{a^2 - 3b^2} \sqrt{3}
$$
and since $a, b, {a^2 - 3b^2}$ are all rational for $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$, $x^{-1} \in H$.

Finally, we can dispose of the case $a^2 - 3b^2 = 0$ by noting that if $a^2 - 3b^2 = 0$ then $\frac{a^2}{b^2} = 3$ and $\sqrt{3}=\frac{a}{b} \in \Bbb{Q}$, a contradiction since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. So $a^2 - 3b^2 \neq 0$.

That last point is what your professor or book was looking for in posing this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, one could note that if $\sqrt{3}=\tfrac{a}{b}\in\Bbb{Q}$ then $H\subset\Bbb{R}^{\ast}\cap\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$, from which it is immediate that $H=\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$, which is clearly a subgroup of $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$.